# How do I make Symfony2 autoload my routing.yml for my bundles that I create in vendors folder?

Tags: php, symfony, vendors

I have created a sample bundle using console. Played with it for a while. Now, I moved it to vendors folder.

Within the vendors folder the folder structure of the bundle is

```
VendorName\VendorName\Bundles\SampleBundle
```

I had added the namespace into `composer/autoload_namespaces.php` and in `AppKernel.php` I successfully registered the bundle. In the `SampleBundle/Resources/config` folder, there is a `routing.yml` which has the previously defined routing information.

When the bundle was inside `src` folder the routing was working fine. I had in `app/config/routing.yml` the below definition

```
biberltd_currency:
    resource: "@VendorNameSampleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

With the above definition I get the following error:

> Cannot import resource "@VendorNameSampleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml from "D:/localdev/www/symfony/app/config\routing.yml". Make sure the "@VendorNameSampleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class.

When I remove the routing definition from `app/config/routing.yml`, the error disappears but the route doesn't work.

Seeing this I checked a lot of the sample bundles but I couldn't find how they handled the routing of bundle controllers for bundles that reside in vendors folder.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Why do you move your bundle into vendor ?

Comment: right now I am trying to learn symfony. but what i have in my mind is to create all non-project specific bundles in vendors folder. I have my own libraries that I have created. For example a currency converter, an image manipulation class etc. etc. that I use in different projects and that I can use in many different projects. I have been reading through symfony documentation and they recommend that vendors folder should have files for generic use whereas src folder should have files that are specific to project.

Comment: A little bit wrong. Don't code under the vendor. Everything goes under src. Also your "generic" bundle. If you want to decouple it, move it outside of symfony, add a composer.json and reference it in your projects composer.json.

Comment: so i assume if I want to share the bundle publicly on github etc. then i should code in vendors folder; am I right? I am a little bit confused with the logic behind of the two folders.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like I had a namespace issue. Now, after correcting the namespace in "`resource:`" including resource in `app/config/routing.yml` works.

```yml
biberltd_currency:
    resource: "@VendorNameSampleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a route loader as described in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/custom_route_loader.html)

Also as pointed by Pazi, configure your [bundle's composer.json](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md)

and finally add in your root composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type":"git",
    "url":"/home/dev/bundle.git"
}
],
"require":{
    "my/bundle":"dev-master"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharing. I have tried the documentation. I only am stuck with this part:

# app/config/routing.yml
AcmeDemoBundle_Extra:
    resource: .
    type: extra

The dot gives an error. It says the resource cannot be loaded. Do you have any idea why that might be an issue?