# Symfony2 never updated routing file automatically when generating crud

Tags: symfony, crud

Why every single time I generate a curd for some entity  , every thing works right except for last action which is updating routing file. I **always** get this :

> Generating the CRUD code: OK Confirm automatic update of the Routing
>   [yes]?   Importing the CRUD routes: FAILED
>
> The command was not able to configure everything automatically.
>   You must do the following changes manually.
>
> - Import the bundle's routing resource in the bundle routing file ....

I know that I can do it manually as the message suggests but I want to understand why it Fails ?

Comment: Do you [import the routes from your bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346821/how-do-i-make-symfony2-autoload-my-routing-yml-for-my-bundles-that-i-create-in-v)?

Comment: yes I import them , but the generation tool seems to have problem when updating routing files. it always fails